# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation UIView corruption

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I'm a bit stuck with a problem that i've got when rotating a UIView.

I have a method called 'updatePositions' that sets the view's current frame to either the left or the right of the superview, and then calls a rotation function to rotate the entire UIView. However when I call this, the frame is set fine, but the rotation corrupts the view completely.

In my layout subviews, I create a label and bezier path, each of which are only created if the label doesn't exist and are laid out using the bounds property of the view.

Am I calling CGAffineTransformMakeRotation in the wrong place?

```
- (void)updatePosition
{
    // If the join overview orientates to north set position
    if (self.joinOverview.doesOrientateToNorth)
        // If the approach track is not south west place the north indicator in the lower left of the diagram
        // if approach track is south west place north indicator in lower right
        if (self.joinOverview.dataItem.approachTrack != VDApproachTrackSouthWest)
            [self setFrame:CGRectMake(-self.superview.frame.origin.x, self.superview.frame.size.height - VIEW_SIZE, VIEW_SIZE, VIEW_SIZE)];
        else
            [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.superview.frame.size.width - VIEW_SIZE, self.superview.frame.size.height - VIEW_SIZE, VIEW_SIZE, VIEW_SIZE)];
    }
    else // If the join overview orientates to the approach track set rotation and position
    {
        // Set the position to the lower left of the view
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(-self.superview.frame.origin.x, self.superview.frame.size.height - VIEW_SIZE, VIEW_SIZE, VIEW_SIZE)];

        // Rotate
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(50));
    }
}


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Super
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // set background colour to transparent
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (!self.northSymbol) {
    // Add 'N' symbol label
    self.northSymbol = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 2, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 2)];
    [self.northSymbol setText:@"N"];
    [self.northSymbol setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [self.northSymbol setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
    [self addSubview:self.northSymbol];

    self.arrow = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithThreePointArrowFromPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2) 
     toPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 20) 
     headWidth:self.bounds.size.width / 2.5];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you're using auto layout which doesn't like transforms, or you're calling `updatePosition` more than once, and thus you're changing `frame` of already transformed view, which will cause you a lot of pain. Add

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

as the first line of `updatePosition`.